# matplotlib clipping pyplot fill

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to clip a specific pyplot fill?
something of the form :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(plots):
    plt.fill(X[i],Y[i]).set_clip_path(the_clipping_polygon[i])
```

Comment: What do you mean by clipping?

Comment: I mean to plot only what is contained within a clipping path. Similar to what ax.set_clip_path() does but applied to specific fills

Comment: Does the above not work? Which problem is there?

Comment: I would like to clip each fill with a specific clipping path. Not all with the same.

Comment: I suppose you will need `the_clipping_polygon1`, `the_clipping_polygon2` etc.